# need help with SED to omit some expressions

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/ /g' a.dat > b.dat
```

This is replacing  `111-11-1111` to spaces , but its also replacing `0111-11-1111` to spaces to... But I want it to ignore `0111-11-1111` (basically if there is 4 numeric characters  instead of 3)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: It's always trivial to write a regexp to match the strings you want it to match (e.g. `.*` matches any string) but much harder to write one that doesn't match strings you **don't** want to match. Without seeing the strings you want to match in context with other strings you don't want to match, we'd just be guessing at how to help you. Which version of sed are you using?

Comment: You can append a space in front of the pattern to ensure that only the string with the pattern you need is replaced. eg: `sed -E 's/ ([0-9]{3})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/ /g' a.dat > b.dat`

This will work given that the numbers `111-11-1111` appear as individual words.

Comment: @mkc what if the data is in a CSV or the string to match appears at the start of a line or ...? We need more info from the OP on the context for their target strings.

Comment: ex: 544-696-4560 is getting replaced with blanks (this is fine)

Comment: 0345-678-6547 is getting replaced with 0 (this should not happen)

Comment: considering X is only numeric, xxx-xx-xxxx should match , xxxx-xx-xxxx ==> should not match

Comment: Don't you have the file a.dat? We are asking that you post a representative part of that file, [edit] the question if you have, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: Both your examples of 544-696-4560  and 0345-678-6547 have **three** digits in the middle, but your regex has `...{3}-...{2}-...{4}`. Is it three or two? Yes, provide an example file, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need additional anchors.

1. Start and end of line (if each entry is in a line)

   ```
   sed -E 's/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}$/ /g' file
   ```
2. Or word boundaries (space-text transitions) (GNU sed):

   ```
   sed -E 's/\<[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}\>/ /g' file
   ```
3. Or capture (and return) an **optional** additional character. But this require that all matched strings are surrounded by additional characters.

   ```
   sed -E 's/([^0-9])[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}([^0-9])/\1 \2/g' file
   ```
4. Or (not in sed) use PCRE that allow lookahead and lookbehind.

   ```
   perl -pe '$_ =~ s/(?<!\d)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}(?!\d)/ /g' file
   ```